# Set no animation in Turtle - Python 3.4?

Tags: python, python-3.x, animation, turtle-graphics

The code below creates a fractal tree. I want to draw it as quick as possible -- I don't want any animation to occur, otherwise it takes a long time to draw. In earlier versions of python, this is achieved with turtle.speed(0), as shown below. This doesn't work in python 3.4

```
import turtle
import random
red = 125
green = 70
blue = 38        
pen = 10
def tree(branchLen, t, red, green, blue, pen):
    if branchLen > 3:
        pen = pen*0.8
        t.pensize(pen)
        red = red - 15
        green = green + 8
    if branchLen > 5:
        angle = random.randrange(10, 70)
        angleTwo = 0.50*angle
        sub = (0.8*(random.randrange(1,24)))
        t.forward(branchLen)
        t.right(angleTwo)
        tree(branchLen-sub,t, red, green, blue, pen)
        t.left(angle)
        tree(branchLen-sub, t, red, green, blue, pen)
        t.right(angleTwo)
        t.backward(branchLen)

def main():
    t = turtle.Turtle()
    t.hideturtle()
    t.speed(0)
    myWin = turtle.Screen()
    t.left(90)
    t.up()
    t.backward(170)
    t.down()
    tree(random.randrange(40,47),t,red,green,blue, pen)
    myWin.exitonclick()

main()
```

It seems the speed module doesn't do anything in 3.4. No matter what number (0-10) used, it's always the same speed and doesn't display an error -- Meaning it still animates.

How can I achieve no animation with turtle in python 3.4? http://interactivepython.org/runestone/static/pythonds/Recursion/graphical.html This is a good place to run the code in Python 2, just replace one of the windows codes with mine.

Comment: According to [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/turtle.html#turtle.speed), *"speed = 0 means that no animation takes place"* is still the case in 3.4. Could you provide a bit more detail than *"doesn't work"*?

Comment: Yeah I've seen the docs. It seems the speed module doesn't do anything in 3.4. No matter what number (0-10) used, it's always the same speed and doesn't display an error -- Meaning it still animates.

Comment: Possibly related: http://bugs.python.org/issue21077

Comment: I don't think this is related, as mine will still draw and work, it just takes a very long time (depending on what random ranges are selected), which is why I want it to not be animated

Comment: Does anyone know about why this doesn't work in 3.4?

Answer (score 3):

I think using [`turtle.tracer(False)`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/turtle.html#turtle.tracer) would be useful as it ignores the animation.

Answer (score 2):

First, I recommend `speed('fastest')` over `speed(0)` to make your intent clear.  Second, before considering `tracer(False)`, first make sure your code is optimal.  Finally, always use `tracer(True)` when you're done drawing as some operations won't behave as expected (e.g. `hideturtle()` at the end of the code) if tracing isn't turned back on.

As far as my second recommendation goes, your combination of `if branchLen > 3:` and `if branchLen > 5:` makes no real difference if you follow the logic so simply do `if branchLen > 5:`.  You pass around colors and manipulate them but never actually use them -- if you want optimal speed, toss incomplete code.  Plus other little optimizations:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle
from random import randrange

PEN_SIZE = 8

def tree(branch_length, turtle, pen_size):
    if branch_length < 5:
        return

    angle = randrange(5, 35)
    double_angle = angle * 2
    sub_length = branch_length - randrange(1, 19)

    turtle.pensize(pen_size)
    pen_size *= 0.8

    turtle.forward(branch_length)
    turtle.right(angle)
    tree(sub_length, turtle, pen_size)
    turtle.left(double_angle)
    tree(sub_length, turtle, pen_size)
    turtle.right(angle)
    turtle.backward(branch_length)

def main():
    myWin = Screen()
    yertle = Turtle(visible=False)

    yertle.left(90)
    yertle.penup()
    yertle.backward(170)
    yertle.pendown()

    myWin.tracer(False)
    tree(randrange(40, 47), yertle, PEN_SIZE)
    myWin.tracer(True)

    myWin.exitonclick()

main()
```

Once you commit to `tracer(False)` then `speed('fastest')` probably stops making a difference so you can optionally toss it.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There you need to use first
screen = Screen() - Get acces to screen module
screen.tracer(0) - To set off all animation
After you need in some step to put animation on with
screen.update()